# Pepper plant leaf curl and "sweating"

Tags: botany, fruit, agriculture, vegetable

The "sweating" and leaf curl have been going on for about a week. I've done some extensive googling and have found mixed diagnoses. For context, the ambient temperature is 74°, I'm using 6,500 K lamps and there are some flies around, but they are small and seemingly harmless. The plants are about 67 days old. Pls help. [image: Leaf curl] [image: Sweating]